# Visual Studio - cannot run any projects: application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, windows-10-desktop

- Windows 10 x64
- Visual Studio 2012 x32
- .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.6

I cannot run/debug/F5 any projects in Visual Studio. I have tried nopCommerce, BlogEngineDotNet, File->New Website, etc. First I was getting an error about .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.0 not being registered, but I installed the fix from Microsoft (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3002339) which resolved that issue.

Now, everytime I try to F5 I get the error below.

[image]

I've searched until I was ready to beat my head against the desk. I found a lot of posts from a few years ago saying to use dependency walker to see if any pre reqs fail, but dependency walker says its only good up to Windows 8.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this issue after I switched the "Default terminal application" to Windows Terminal. I had to restart Visual Studio and then it worked again but using Windows Terminal caused other issues so I had to revert and restart VS again.

As @Trout.Z mentioned, you may also want to enable the **Automatically close the console when debugging stops** option in Visual Studio. You can find it in the options under **Debugging** > **General**.

Comment: I got this exact problem on Windows 11 with my VS 2022 C/C++ environment, and this answer has solved it (at least I've compiled and ran my program 5 times now without a single error).

Comment: Set the console window to auto close, according to "To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.", save me from restarting VS2022 over and over again for this 0xc0000142 issue.

Comment: Yeah, that was a new option I found yesterday as well! It certainly has saved me from having zombie console windows spread around my taskbar. Nice callout. I added it to my answer to make it easier for those from the future 

Comment: I too had this on Win 11 / VS 2022 / Windows Terminal. It was enough for me to toggle the `Default Terminal Application` in Windows Terminal, and restart VS.

Comment: Yes.. This was the problem for me

Answer (score -4):

uninstall **Visual Studio 2012 x32**  and install new `Visual Studio 2012 x64` because your os is 64 bit

above code helps you to make it working.

Comment: I can assure you from personal experience this isn't the issue.  I haven't found the issue on my machine yet ... but this isn't it.  I'm in a nice tight edit-compile-run cycle on my dev machine and this program *was* working fine then this (0xc0000142) started happening after one particular batch of edits.